# Silverlight schedule an event at a specific time

Tags: silverlight, events, scheduling

I'm trying to find a way to trigger a Silverlight event to occur at a specific time of the day.  The app will be run out of browser and will be running all the time. I have found some methods that use a timer to fire an event every minute and then check if it is the correct time to do something, but that sounds messy.  Is there some way of firing an event at, for example, 10:34AM on 23 September 2010?

Answer (score 2):

If you want timer to survive application restart I suggest use polling and persist scheduled tasks somewhere.

Otherwise just set timer interval to timespan between current and scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a feature in Silverlight. If you don't like the polling approach, you could always get the difference between DateTime.Now and the target time and set a timer for that long. Though I do not know how reliable that would be.

Comment: A `Timer` is the tool for the job, I don't see any reason for it to be any less reliable than any other approach.  This answer would be greatly enhanced with a simple code example.

Comment: Timers are intended for short intervals, so I'm not sure if this will be accurate. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any control that does what you ask for. Here are the timers that I am familiar with:

- System.Threading.Timer(interval) - Generate recurring events (Purely numeric timing without UI updates)
- System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(..) - Use in a threaded context (WPF/Silverlight)
- System.Windows.Forms.Timer() - Use windows forms message loop (WinForms in main UI thread)

I think your best bet is to use a DispatcherTimer with an interval of, say, 30 seconds, and then match the actual time with the expected time and date. <strike>From what I remember such timers are intended for small intervals, so bigger intervals will be less accurate. (I speak under correction)</strike>

**EDIT**: [MSDN remarks on timing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx): "Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) operations are placed on the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities."

Comment: You mentioned accuracy of long intervals. Surely then the best case is to wait one long interval first (a bit shorter than the time required, i.e. allowing for largest known error), then start polling at a smaller interval until the time is reached?

Comment: @Enough Already: Sure, you could do that. It all depends on how much time you want to invest on building a solution. One tick every 30 seconds won't kill your CPU.

Comment: I ran a few tests, and DispatcherTimer is fairly accurate when not much else is happening. No need for polling after all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I still haven't found anything, but ended up using a StoryBoard as the timing component, as DispatcherTimer runs in the same thread as the UI, whereas StoryBoard doesn't.

You can read more about a comparison between the two here.

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/11/09/69731.aspx

Comment: There's no reason you should care that the timer is running on the UI thread because you don't need high resolution or consistency. A Storyboard might need to run every exactly 10 ms, which a DispatcherTimer can't do. But you need resolution of a minute or second, not milliseconds, so it should be irrelevant to you.